# Finding a side of a triange

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In triangle $ABC$, $a= 5$, $\sin(A) = .3$, and $\sin(B) = .2$. What is the length of side $b$? I am not sure what to do since I have never encountered a problem like this where the sine of an angle is given but not the angle itself.

Comment: Have you tried doing Law of Sines?

Comment: Yes, I have already used laws of sines but I end up getting the wrong answer. This is for summer assignments and according to the answer sheet that the teacher has provided it's 10/3 but I keep getting 15/2. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Show your attempt. You probably solved the proportion incorrectly.

Comment: I have edited my response with a solution @idk oof, please double check as I see you edited the values of sin(A) and sin(B)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Using law of sines: $\frac{a}{sin(A)} = \frac{b}{sin(B)} = \frac{c}{sin(C)}$. Try substituting and solve for b.

Here is a solution:
Using law of sines:
$\frac{a}{sin(A)} = \frac{b}{sin(B)} \implies \frac{5}{0.3} = \frac{b}{0.2}$. Cross multiply to get $0.2 * 5 = 0.3 * b \implies b = \frac{1}{0.3} \implies b = \frac{10}{3}$